# URL redirect problem

Tags: redirect, urls

I have 2 pages in my wordpress 3.0.1 site with 2 urls

www.mysite.co.uk/sub-page/child-of-sub-page/accommodation/

and

www.mysite.co.uk/accommodation/

however any link in my site to www.mysite.co.uk/accommodation/ goes to www.mysite.co.uk/sub-page/child-of-sub-page/accommodation/ instead

is this a bug in wordpress 3.0.1? or is there a way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing this behavior in my test install, using the page hierarchy you have described.

http://img.skitch.com/20101028-kmdmrb11pyb5h281m9r8j74993.jpg

I can access both the top-level accommodation page and the child page. Do you happen to have the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe pages cannot have the same slug, even if the full path is different. This is indeed a limitation in WordPress. I believe others active on this site, like Mike Schinkel, can tell you where the Trac ticket is.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mysite.co.uk/accommodation/ goes to URL not found so you need to redirect it to the correct URL

You can do this if your theme offers built in 301 redirects or install a plugin to do this. Otherwise cPanel offers redirects